# VC++/CLI: How to prevent an unmanaged object from being destroyed when it goes out of scope?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, interop

I have a third-party unmanaged C++ library which has two classes, let's call them `ClassA` and `ClassB`. `ClassA` has a method, let's call it `getTheB()`, which returns an instance of `ClassB` - it does not return a pointer to the instance, but the instance itself.

I now wrote a managed wrapper for `ClassA` which in turn has a method `getTheB()` which returns a managed wrapper wrapping the `ClassB`.

The original `ClassB` object from the third-party library has to be handed over to my managed wrapper via its pointer, like:

```
ThirdParty::ClassB db = delegateForClassA -> getTheB();
ManagedClassB^ mb = gcnew ManagedClassB(&db);
```

However, when my wrapped `getTheB()` of my `ClassA` wrapper finishes and the scope ends, the `ManagedClassB` instance contains a dangling reference to the third-party `ClassB` and the destructor of the latter one is called, leading to funny results when accessing methods of `ClassB`.

In my other question, I was told to somehow store the original `ClassB` object, but I don't know how.

So, how do I keep the third-party `ClassB` instance alive?

Comment: If this class has a copy constructor you could instance it like new ClassB(delegate->getTheB()) or if it has an assignment operator you could just assign it to the new object. Also you could make a wrapper class which you pass the instance as a reference like: class Wrapper { public: Wrapper(ClassB& ref) : _ref(ref) {} private: ClassB& _ref; } Then you instanciate it with new Wrapper(delegate->getTheB()); It is then in the scope of the wrapper object if it is ok to say it like that.

Comment: The third-party `ClassB` has no visible public constructors, instances are only returned by methods from other classes in the library. With your second approach, where does `_ref` come from? Is it "built-in" to VC++ or in a library?

Comment: No, it's the variable name. Actually i dont know if it really is created within the wrapper scope or it is a dangling reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either change getTheB to return a heap-allocated ClassB, or have ManagedClassB make his own copy of the db object.

Update for the copy:

I assume ManagedClassB's constructor looks something like

```
public ref class ManagedClassB
{
public:
    ManagedClassB(ClassB* p)
        : m_p(p) { }
...
private:
    ClassB* m_p;
};
```

You should simply change it to

```
public ref class ManagedClassB
{
public:
    ManagedClassB(const ClassB& b)
        : m_b(b) { }
...
private:
    ClassB m_b;
};
```

or

```
public ref class ManagedClassB
{
public:
    ManagedClassB(ClassB* p)
        : m_p(new ClassB(*p)) { }
...
private:
    ClassB* m_p;
};
```

Comment: The original `getTheB` returns the actual object and not a pointer, and I do not have the library's source code, so I cannot change that.

Comment: Obviously, if the getTheB is returning a ClassB object by value, then ClassB is either copyable or movable. If it is copyable, make a copy inside ManagedClassB. Otherwise, move it.

Comment: So I could simply do something like: `ClassB db = delegateForClassA -> getTheB(); ClassB* dbCopy = new ClassB(&db);`? I will try this tomorrow.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I will edit my message to show some pseudocode

Comment: Your second example works (where you call `m_p(new ClassB(*p)) { }`). For the first one, the compiler complains that mixed types are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You should be allocating the db in the scope appropriate for your use.  You know what is best for you, be it a static member of something, or a basic global, or whatever.  The scope must remain valid as long as you need db, and execution can go out of scope when you're done with it.

Comment: I cannot because the `ClassB` has no publicly-visible constructors. The only way to get an instance is said `getTheB()` method. I cannot make managed methods return direct instances of unmanaged classes, and when I return `&db`, I have a dangling reference as soon as the method returning `&db` finishes.

Comment: I expected some kind of a constructor, if only a default constructor, where you currently have it being allocated.  It would be allocated and (default) constructed as it comes into scope, then assigned (overwritten) when execution reaches the ->getTheB() call.  Sorry, it's hard to let go of constructors in such an absolute way.

Comment: There is a hack, if you have no other way whatsoever.  You can use your own copy of the library header, change private to public for the constructor, and the compiler will grant you access.  It works, but it's dirty, and it wasn't me that told you.  ;-)

Comment: Aaaaand apparently this answer got anonymously down voted for me mentioning that.

Comment: No, it was not downvoted for this, but KABoissoneault's answer did the trick for me.